# How do you get the username in Silverlight Out-Of-Browser (SLOOB) apps?

Tags: .net, silverlight

We currently use Silverlight within the browser.  ASP.NET writes the Windows Authenticated user name to the ASPX page that the Silverlight control is on. The username is passed as a parameter in to the control when it loads.

How would you get the username with an out-of-browser application?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the recommended approach to work around this was to store any details like this when you perform the OOB installation, that way you can still access them when you start OOB.

Comment: Would the username be fixed for the user or the machine?

Comment: I think the OOB installation is per-user, so would be fixed for the user unless they change username. Your other option as of SL4 would be COM interop but of course that will only work on Windows boxes.